# No operating system will boot after attempting to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 8 on a Lenovo T530

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, 13.04, windows-8, grubrescue

I've had to retry this a million times, and it's doing my head in. Please help me.

I resized my partitions from within Windows 8, and disabled everything I was supposed to, I installed 13.04 from a multi-boot LiveUSB. Once installed, I could get into Ubuntu, but not Windows 8. After running boot-repair from Ubuntu on my LiveUSB, the machine boots into this error:

> error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.

And it gives me the grub-recovery thing.

How do I get this working? At the moment I can have only Windows installed, or only Ubuntu. I want both.

Comment: using 64bit image? for uefi you must use 64bit image

Comment: I am using a 64-bit image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to follow this guide

[Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting#General_Troubleshooting_Preparation)

to recover the installation of grub!

Comment: After re-installing Ubuntu, and then following that guide again, I got the same problem. grub-repair gave me this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5641806.

Comment: mmmm seems you have to reinstall grub in sdb5

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.it/2011/06/recover-grub-live-ubuntu-cd-pendrive.html

Comment: I can't follow the first step because it doesn't like GPT. Should I try this all again installing everything on the system that isn't GPT?

Comment: You can try, I don't know if this work...

Comment: I can view the contents of both my Windows partition, and my Ubuntu partition. Will this let me do anything?

Comment: Yes ;) you have to login as root

Comment: What can I do to fix this this way? What would I need to sign in as root to do?